# how to join three average result into one result in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a three queries like this:

```
select  avg( datediff(mi,t.dtime, t.PAICdate )) as Avgparkingtime 
from (
    select top 10 * from transaction_tbl where locid=6 order by transactID desc
) t

select  avg( datediff(mi,t.Paydate, t.DelDate )) as AvgDelivarytime  
from (
    select top 10 * from transaction_tbl where locid=6 order by transactID desc
) t


select  avg( datediff(mi,t.dtime, t.DelDate )) as Avgstaytime 
from (
    select top 10 * from transaction_tbl where locid=6 order by transactID desc
) t
```

am getting out put like this:

```
Avgparkingtime
--------------
23

AvgDelivarytime
---------------
38
Avgstaytime
-----------
39
```

how i can join these three quires..i want to get these three result in one row..
my expected out put like this:

```
 Avgparkingtime     AvgDelivarytime    Avgstaytime
  --------------     --------------    ------------
    23                    38                39
```

how i can do thise?

Comment: Have you tried with `UNION` among them?

Comment: yes sir,,that time result is coming in three rows

Comment: i want to get result in one row

Comment: How this one `select  avg( datediff(mi,t.dtime, t.DelDate )) as Avgstaytime, avg( datediff(mi,t.dtime, t.PAICdate )) as  Avgparkingtime, avg( datediff(mi,t.Paydate, t.DelDate )) as AvgDelivarytime
from (
    select top 10 * from transaction_tbl where locid=6 order by transactID desc
) t`

Comment: sir,,can i have ask one more doubt please??\